# Is there a way to reference an ALAsset across iOS restore?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

The use case is that I want to organize the photos in the camera roll but be able to do so before and after a user restores from backup. The URL for the ALAsset changes when the photo is restored.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seriously, no answer on this yet? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible. Maybe when one of these events happens (restore or system upgrade) you update the url based on their date (if you store the date too)?