# How can be detected when an app has been restored from a backup?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

ALAssetPropertyAssetURL property is a handy way to store a reference to an ALAsset but during system restore (or upgrade) some assets [might change this property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688127/is-there-a-way-to-reference-an-alasset-across-ios-restore/19978121). While there might be some workarounds to update the assets reference url, how do I detect when this is needed? System updgrade is easy, but how do I detect when an app has been restored from a backup, also if this happened in the same device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your app launches, look in the documents for a file of a known name (DidLaunch.txt, say), and if its not there, create it, and set its metadata "Do Not Backup". On every launch, look for that file - if its there, you previously launched on this device. If its not there, this is a fresh launch.

Comment: This looks bloody brilliant! Will try and let you know if it worked and set it as correct answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bookmark objects are how I typically maintain access to resources that the user may shift on me.

[From the NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Starting in OS X v10.6, the NSURL class provides a facility for creating and using bookmark objects. A bookmark provides a persistent reference to a file-system resource. When you resolve a bookmark, you obtain a URL to the resource’s current location. A bookmark’s association with a file-system resource (typically a file or folder) usually continues to work if the user moves or renames the resource, or if the user relaunches your app or restarts the system.

I don't know about how it would handle restorations from backups (sounds like you'd be digging deep in the bowels of the OS to comprehend that one), but It's probably your best option regardless.

Comment: It looks like URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:error: is available from iOS 5.0, so I guess same techniques should work also on iOS. A bit scared of starting saving NSData instead of a NSString (especially if used as key).